# useState won't render a page

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to rewrite the CV React app so that it uses Hooks. I have this code below:

```
const App = () => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState({
    name: "",
    email: "",
    phone: "",

    schoolName: "",
    studyTitle: "",
    completion: "",
    studyStartDate: "",
    studyEndDate: "",

    companyName: "",
    positionTitle: "",
    mainTasks: "",

    isFormSaved: false,
    btnText: "Save info"
  });

  const handleButtonClick = () => {
    setValues({
      isFormSaved: !values.isFormSaved
    });

    if (!values.isFormSaved) {
      setValues({ btnText: "Edit info" });
    } else {
      setValues({ btnText: "Save info" });
    }
  };

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setValues({ ...values, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  const overview = (
    <section className="overview">
      <Overview data={values} />
    </section>
  );

  const form = (
    <section className="editInfo">
      <GeneralInfo
        onChange={handleChange}
        disabled={values.isFormSaved}
        placeholder={values}
      />
      <Experience
        onChange={handleChange}
        disabled={values.isFormSaved}
        placeholder={values}
      />
      <Practice
        onChange={handleChange}
        disabled={values.isFormSaved}
        placeholder={values}
      />
    </section>
  );

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <h1>CV Application</h1>
      {values.isFormSaved ? overview : form}
      <button onClick={handleButtonClick}>{values.btnText}</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I have trouble woth the page rendering. The button works but the desired effect - rendering of the preview site is not working. I suspect the fault lies in the App.js code above.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently overwriting all values when changing the button text. You are probably just translating your react component code to hooks too literally. `useEffect` doesn't work exactly the same as `setState`, it always writes the entire value, because it's meant for state variables, not for the entire state.

It's easy to fix though:

```
    if (!values.isFormSaved) {
      setValues(values => ({ ...values, btnText: "Edit info" }));
    } else {
      setValues(values => ({ ...values, btnText: "Save info" }));
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly!